# How to create a 'sanitized' copy of our SQL Server database?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

We're a manufacturing company, and we've hired a couple of data scientists to look for patterns and correlation in our manufacturing data. We want to give them a copy of our reporting database (SQL 2014), but it must be in a 'sanitized' form. This means that all table names get converted to 'Table1', 'Table2' etc., and column names in each table become 'Column1', 'Column2' etc. There will be roughly 100 tables, some having 30+ columns, and some tables have 2B+ rows.

I know there is a hard way to do this. This would be to manually create each table, with the sanitized table name and column names, and then use something like SSIS to bulk insert the rows from one table to another. This would be rather time consuming and tedious because of the manual SSIS column mapping required, and manual setup of each table.

I'm hoping someone has done something like this before and has a much faster, more efficienct, way.

By the way, the 'sanitized' database will have no indexes or foreign keys. Also, it may seem to make any sense why we would want to do this, but this is what was agreed to by our Director of Manufacturing and the data scientists, as the first round of analysis which will involve many rounds.

Comment: What's the purpose of doing so? It will only make them harder to extract any reasonable conclusion. The only thing so sanitize would be  confidential data, like emails, passwords and the like.

Comment: Just for curiosity wouldn't you want to sanitize the data rather than the table/column names? (Such as obfuscating client names?) Additionally, do your data scientists need foreign keys intact?

Comment: @Hankinsoft - No foreign key or indexes in the database. I've updated my question to reflect this.

Comment: There are times when you need to say to the director of manufacturing that this won't help at all.

Comment: my approach would be to duplicate the database and then write some sql script to do the rename using the system database tables, which contain all the metadata youd need to make this a quick job.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You basically want to scrub the data and objects, correct?  Here is what I would do.

1. Restore a backup of the db.
2. Drop all objects not needed (indexes, constraints, stored procedures, views, functions, triggers, etc.)
3. Create a table with two columns, populate the table, each row has orig table name and new table name
4. Write a script that iterates through the table, roe by row, and renames your tables.  Better yet, put the data into excel, and create a third column that builds the tsql you want to build, then cut/paste and execute in ssms.
5. Repeat step 4, but for all columns.  Best to query sys.columns to get all the objects you need, put to excel, and build your tsql
6. Repeat again for any other objects needed.

Backip/restore will be quicker than dabbling in SSIS and data transfer.

Answer (score -2):

They can see the data but they can't see the column names?   What can that possibly accomplish?   What are you protecting by not revealing the table or column names?   How is a data scientist supposed to evaluate data without context?   Without a FK all I see is a bunch of numbers on a column named colx.  What are expecting to accomplish?   Get a confidentially agreement.   Consider a FK columns customerID verses a materialID.  Patterns have widely different meanings and analysis.   I would correlate a quality measure with materialID or shiftID but not with a customerID.

Oh look there is correlation between tableA.colB and tableX.colY.  Well yes that customer is college team and they use aluminum bats.

On top of that you strip indexes (on tables with 2B+ rows) so the analysis they run will be slow.  What does that accomplish?

As for the question as stated do a back up restore.  Using system table drop all triggers, FK, index, and constraints.  Don't forget to drop the triggers and constraints - that may disclose some trade secret. Then rename columns and then tables.

Comment: I think you're missing the point. This is required by an external party. Those are the people that would be able to answer your questions. The OP simply has a requirement.

Comment: @BobHorn See last paragraph

Comment: This answer does not answer the question and is just sarcastic. How do you know what the requirements are for the OP? Even your last paragraph is sarcastic. Someone with a rep as high as yours should know better and be more professional.

Comment: @Blam The OP was looking for help like what Greg provided in his answer. I think we all agree that this concept *in general* is a bad idea. But that's not the point here. If you want to mention that while providing an actual answer that helps the OP, great. But that's not what this answer does.

Comment: @BobHorn And I did provide an actual answer that I think is better than Greg.  If you read the system tables and do it in that order you don't need to manually drop stuff nor put stuff in Excel.

Comment: I think the issue is that 90% of your answer is not about solving the problem. The 10% that was about solving the problem seems vague. I think if you provided the answer first, with more detail, that would make your answer a good one.

Comment: @bob I agree it is not an ideal answer.  About 1/3 of my job is loading and scrubbing data and much of it is confidential data.  It is a real answer and right or wrong in real life I would argue with the requirements first.   If my boss told me to format backup tapes to save money I would argue with that my time cost more than a tape.   On the surface it is absurd (to me).